# pointInside:withEvent: called when typing on keyboard on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've stumbled upon this issue and I'm not sure what would be the best way to deal with it. The issue is very easy to reproduce and I've put [a simple demo project on GitHub for demonstration](https://github.com/droussel/TestPointInside), but here's the gist of it.

Let's say I have an iPad app with a UITextField in it's main view. Below it is a small UIView subclass which implements pointInside:withEvent:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL inside = CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point);
    NSLog(@"pointInside Called");
    return inside;
}
```

Running the app, the pointInside method gets called if I tap anywhere on the screen BUT the keyboard; typing on the keyboard does not trigger the pointInside method.

While leaving the keyboard up, I then send the app in the background and then come back to the app.  Now, every time I type on the keyboard, the pointInside method gets called! The only way I found to 'fix' the issue is to set the UITextEffectsWindow as keyAndVisible; but this is not really viable as it could introduce other side effects.

Any idea how to deal with this? My problem is that we were using this method in our app to dismiss a popup when the user taps outside of it. But there is a UITextField in the popup and we obviously don't want to discard the popup when the user starts typing in it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cause of all of the false positives is coordinate system.  The code asks whether a touch is within the bounds of the view receiving a touch.  Of course it is.  Instead check the point against some subview's frame.  Even better, attach a tap gesture recognizer to the view(s) where a tap should cause the text field to resign first responder.

Comment: but the point is in view coordinates

Comment: This doesn't explain why pointInside is not called when typing on the keyboard before the app goes to the background but does afterward.

The check is working alright and there is not false positive. The only problem is that the method gets called when typing on the keyboard in one case but not the other.

Comment: I agree. I was trying to understand what danh meant

Comment: Sorry Daij-Djan, I was responding to danh comment's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with a UITapGestureRecognizer added to the UIWindow. The custom view adds it upon moving to a new window and removes it when being deallocated; works fine and solves my problem :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *outsideTapRecognizer;

- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow
{
    if(self.outsideTapRecognizer){
        [self.window removeGestureRecognizer:self.outsideTapRecognizer];
    }

    self.outsideTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOutside:)];
    [newWindow addGestureRecognizer:self.outsideTapRecognizer];
}

- (void)tapOutside:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    BOOL inside = CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]);
    if (!inside) {
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.window removeGestureRecognizer:self.outsideTapRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no real answer and it does sound wrong BUT I have two workarounds

a) check the event's touches and ignore the request if it has no touches for your window

b) use a gestureRecognizer that lies above the popup to determine what to do to the open state of the popup

c) (this is what we do ... old code from before recognisers) override touchesBegan & co on the window and pass clicks to a delegate

Comment: Strangely / Unfortunately, event.allTouches is empty so I can't check to which window they belong.

Comment: It's a UITouchesEvent; I expected touches :-)

Comment: I totally agree -- leaves what i called b